# Intellij Java/Scala mixed project, cascading errors in editor

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

my problem is that if for example in one method, I will put **invalid** value, that does not match return type, as a result in editor I see cascading errors, for example another class extending trait that has this method with return type error shows error on trait position, I see some weird errors even in imports, even not connected to that issue..

I will paste some code, here is a trait that has validation method with this type error:

```
trait UserRestValidators {

  final def validateUserProfileRequest(request: UserProfileRequest): Either[TCError, Unit] = {
    val peselVal = validatePeselWithBirthDate(request)

    val validations = List(peselVal)
    val errors      = validations.filter(_.isLeft).flatMap(_.swap.toOption)
    if (errors.isEmpty) Right(())
    else {
      val mergedError = errors.map(_.error).mkString("\\n")
      Left(GenericError(mergedError))
    }
    Left(666)
  }
```

and errors in class extending this trait:

In few places I see errors:

> Stable identifier required, but <error Cyclic reference involving val
> >#...

[image]
[image]

and what is interesting.. code that is using this `validateUserProfileRequest` does not show any errors..

any ideas how to fix those code editor issues ?

Idea version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-221.5921.22, built on June 21, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.15+10-b2043.56 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
```

sample project: [github-repo](https://github.com/maciejbak85/scala-maven-example)
thanks

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: Is it possible to provide sample project example?

Comment: try reinstalling your Scala plugin and/or update it.

Comment: @y.bedrov https://github.com/maciejbak85/scala-maven-example

Comment: ah looks like its scala 3 plugin issue.. with scala 2.13.8 its showing 1 errors instead of 10000 ;)